# How to send Mat H=findHomography return to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, mex

I try to use the OpenCV Function findHomography. I use Mex OpenCV. My Problem is how can I return the Mat H Array to MATLAB. 
I hope anybody can help me :-)

Example code is:

```
enter code here

#include "opencvmex.hpp"
#include "math.h"
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], 
            int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]){


    //create "CV_32FC2" Array       
    Mat srcPoints(4,1,CV_32FC2);

    srcPoints.at<int>(0)=221;
    srcPoints.at<int>(1)=227;              
    srcPoints.at<int>(2)=237;
    srcPoints.at<int>(3)=255;

    Mat dstPoints(4,1,CV_32FC2);

    dstPoints.at<int>(0)=120;
    dstPoints.at<int>(1)=67;
    dstPoints.at<int>(2)=91;
    dstPoints.at<int>(3)=113;


    // findHomography

    Mat H;

    int method=0;
    double ransacReprojThreshold=3;
    int maxIters = 2000;
    double confidence = 0.995;        

     H = findHomography(srcPoints,dstPoints);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ocvMxArrayFromMat_{DataType}`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocvmxarrayfrommat_datatype.html), in your case probably best to use:

```
plhs[0]=ocvMxArrayFromMat_double(H);
```

[Here is the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/opencv-interface.html) of the OpenCV interface, so you can look at the available fucntions.

Comment: Hey Ander,  thank for answering :-),

that I can use the "MexArray" I need to add an advanced package, but I need to solve my Problem with the default opportunities, which MEX contains.

/thx

Comment: @UdoTamegger aren't you already using it? You have `#include "opencvmex.hpp"` in your code, not just `opencv`. Can you link to the library you are using? You mention in your post that you are using mex openCV

Comment: Hey @Ander Biguri, I am using the official Matlab OpenCV - Interface.
https://de.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-opencv.html

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47953-computer-vision-system-toolbox-opencv-interface